# using import foundation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, compass

In assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
I have these lines

```
@import "compass/css3";

@import "foundation";

@import 'foundation-icons';
```

But `@import "foundation"` fails with this errror

```
Invalid CSS after "": expected media query list, was ""only screen an..."
  (in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:143)
```

Here is my Gemfile

```
gem 'rails-dev-tweaks'
gem "compass-rails"
gem "zurb-foundation", '~> 4.0.0'
gem "foundation-icons-sass-rails"
gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'
```

What is the problem? I am on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already run:

```
rails g foundation:install
```